# Read system call not detecting End of file

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

I have connected a modem to my pc(linux) through serial port and i am trying to write to and read from modem using write and read system call.During reading read system call blocks after reading all data from modem,in my code i have made check for eof  as shown below

```
  while(1)
  {
      if((rd_cnt =read(fd, &str, 1)) <=0)
    {
            perror("Read to dev failed");
            printf("error no=%d\n",errno);
            break;
    }

        printf("char =%c ->  hex=%x rd_cnt=%d\n",str,str,rd_cnt);
        sleep(3);
        str=0;
 }      

 if(rd_cnt==0)
    printf("EOF met\n");
```

but i have never got eof,i wanted to read all the data send from modem till i meet end of file.
Please guide me.

Comment: Where is your `while(1)` loop terminating?

Comment: How do you expect the serial port to know when the end of file occurs? Typically you don't want to hang up the serial connection after transmitting a file, which is why protocols (such as the venerable ZMODEM) were developed to handle file transfer mixed with ordinary (interactive) traffic.

Comment: in following if condition if the return value of read is <=1 it will terminate

Comment: username:@unwind,i am not expecting serial port to let me know i expect the read system call to let me know.In man pages they have said that read system call will return "0" on reaching end of file.

Comment: I do not actually understand how modem works, but maybe there is no EOF from your modem.

Comment: @Sachin: Wait, do you want to (1) know when reaching the end of file while reading it from disk, (2) know when the serial port is closed on the other side, or (3) know when the file has been fully transmitted over the serial connection?

Comment: @Medinoc: I want to know whether my read system call has red entire data that has been sent from other end.

Comment: @Sachin: Serial ports don't know the other end has finished sending for good. You have to implement yourself a protocol for doing this (such as sending the length first).

Answer (score 2):

change your code like this

```
if((rd_cnt =read(fd, &str, sizeof(str))) <=0)
    {
            perror("Read to dev failed");
            printf("error no=%d\n",errno);
            break;
    }
```

That is ok to check the `EOF` condition.

No need to write this code again as you are already checking this.

```
//if(rd_cnt==0)
    //printf("EOF met\n");
```

Comment: i have given that statement to check whether read has got EOF or not,let me know a way to detect EOF.

Comment: @Sachin... You are already checking that where you are calling `read` system call.

Comment: If there is no EOF sent, one usally never can know when the file is completely read in.... one approach would be to use a timeout, perhaps depending on baud rate, for example

Comment: @krishna inside if loop only