# How to check whether read system call has read entire data or not

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

I need to know whether `read` system call has read entire data or not. By default `read` system call blocks if there is no data in the buffer, but it does not ensure that data has been completely read. Please let me know a proper way to confirm.

In man pages it has been said that `read` system call returns `0` when it has met end of file I have tried that also, and `read` was not returning `0` at all.

```
wr_cnt =write(fd, "AT+CGMI\r", sizeof("AT+CGMI\r"));

  if(wr_cnt<0)
        perror("Write to dev failed");
  else
       printf("No.of bytes written=%d\n",wr_cnt);

  while(1)
  {
      //rd_cnt =read(fd, &str, 1);
      if((rd_cnt =read(fd, &str, 1)) <=0)
    {
            perror("Read to dev failed");
            printf("error no=%d\n",errno);
            break;
    }

        printf("char =%c ->  hex=%x rd_cnt=%d\n",str,str,rd_cnt);
        sleep(3);
        str=0;
 }      

 if(rd_cnt==0)
    printf("EOF met\n");
```

Comment: are you trying to read a file or a stream?

Comment: @mbratch:hi please look into the attached code.

Comment: @mbratch... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18399812/read-system-call-not-detecting-end-of-file/18400047?noredirect=1#comment27026567_18400047

Comment: @theolodis,I am writing and reading to stream device file(Modem) connected via serial port.

Comment: Have you not been taught about `select()`?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams no,but why this read system call is not reading EOF

Comment: That "0" for end of file will not be returned on a partial read. That is, if there are 14 bytes remaining to be read, and you are reading 16 bytes at a time, the next read() will return 14, and the following one will return 0 -- unless the io device is one that could produce more data later, in which case the call will block until that happens.

Comment: @mah what u have said is correct,in my case also it happens the same,after reading entire data read system call is not sending EOF it is blocking.

Comment: Read @mah's comment again. The second part "unless the io device is one that could produce more data later, in which case the call will block until that happens". A serial port will never have an EOF because more data could be sent at some point in the future. To know that your read is complete you must have some kind of protocol either you would need to know how much data you expect to read in total, or terminate the read when you find special characters (such as newlines) or in the case of a timeout.

Comment: @tinman;Thanks your comments was useful.

Answer (score 2):

By default, `read` will not return zero, indicating EOF, unless it really is the end of the file, or the connection has been closed. If a stream connection is still open, but there happens to be no data available right now, `read` will just "hang" until something arrives.

There are two solutions to this.

1. Set the file descriptor to *non-blocking* mode. If there is no data then `read` will return `-1`, and `errno` will be set to `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` (you should probably also check `EINTR`, as a matter of course, in any case). There might be other reasons why input would block, so you should retry for a short time just to be sure.
2. Use `select` *before* read. It's a bit more verbose in your code, but it's more efficient at run time. `select` only returns when it can be sure a subsequent read would not block, or it reaches your timeout. You can interpret a timeout as "EOF" for streaming data. If you are reading input from multiple streams then `select` is an absolute must.